# Modifying default Wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search

Right now I'm using a default wordpress search:

```
<input type="text" name="s"  placeholder="Search here" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
```

When you enter and hit search, by default it goes to:

mywebsite.com/?s=query

What I want is to go to:

mywebsite.com/query

without "?s="

Basically, I won't be using it for an actual search, but more of appending the value after mywebsite.com/

Maybe there's just an easy php code for a form?

Sorry I'm new.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://theme-fusion.com/6-wordpress-search-plugins-replace-default-search/

Comment: This is how a normal GET form sends its parameters, in the query string. You could either  intervene in the standard form submission with JavaScript (prevent regular submit, read the field value, create target URL from it, redirect there by assigning it to location.href), or redirect any requests with such a query string to the new URL format from the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Found the working solution:

```
    <form name="menu_search" action="load.php" method="get" onsubmit="document.location.href = 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/'+this.q.value+''; return false;" >

    <input name="q" id="videoSearch" />

  </form>
```